# BASH-create a 'www-data' crontab that runs a PHP file

Tags: php, cron, ubuntu-18.04, www-data, nextcloud

I need to get this to run in a cron file in `/etc/cron.d/`:

`*/15 * * * * php -f /var/www/nextcloud/cron.php`

...but, my scripts don't run. It's permissions are set to 644 and I need to create it with a Shell/BASH script. I'm using:

echo "*/15 * * * * php -f /var/www/nextcloud/cron.php" > /etc/cron.d/nccron

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an much easier way (must be done as `root` user)

`echo '*/15 * * * *  www-data php -f /var/www/nextcloud/cron.php' > /etc/cron.d/wwwcron`

I'd use SINGLE quotes not DOUBLE quotes to prevent any possibility of expansion of the '*' metasymbol.

Comment: You, sir, are a gentleman and a scholar.

Answer (score 0):

1. To run a PHP cron job, `www-data` needs to do a crontab job itself, using `php -f` as the [user] inside the cronjob line:

`*/15 * * * * php -f /var/www/nextcloud/cron.php`

(These are Nextcloud instructions. They got it right, don't try to hack this, in my case.)

2. `www-data` must run the cron job itself as a crontab (not `/etc/cron.d`, et al)

Normally, this is set up from the terminal:

*Running as `root` in this example...*

`crontab -u www-data -e` ...add the cronjob string (above).

`crontab -u www-data -l` ...and it should match.

*But, I need this done as a script, not `crontab -e` in the terminal.*

3. Do this via shellscript (danger?):

crontab jobs are in: `/var/spool/cron/crontabs/USER`

with permissions: `-rw------- ... www-data crontab`

The script that worked:

*Running as `root` in this example...*

```
echo "*/15 * * * * php -f /var/www/nextcloud/cron.php" >> /var/spool/cron/crontabs/www-data
chown www-data:crontab /var/spool/cron/crontabs/www-data
chmod 600 /var/spool/cron/crontabs/www-data
```

Oh, Happy Day!